# Is it the right way to determine the coefficients?

Tags: linear-transformations

I am having trouble with understanding the logical completeness of a solution of exercise on my textbook (*Linear Algebra Done Right*).

 we have $Tp=(bp(1)p(2),c\sin p(0))$ &$p\in P(R)$. Prove that if T is a linear map, then $b=c=0$. 
It answers:
consider $f(x)=\pi/2$ and $g(x)=\pi/2$, then they both are polynomials. So examining the property of the linear map: $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$. we have $T(f+g) = (b\pi^2,c\sin(\pi))$ and $T(f)+T(g) = (b\pi^2/4,csin(\pi/2))+(b\pi^2/4,csin(\pi/2)) = (b\pi^2/2,2csin(\pi/2))$
Thus b = c = 0.
My logic is that since the $f$ and $g$ are only two instances of the polynomials, using which to determine the value of $b$ and $c$ can be dangerous. Because we did not try polynomials with degree 1,2,3,4..... I think the more appropriate way to prove is using the property of polynomials but it would make this way more complex.

I am curious about your opinion. I am really confused about whether I am being critical or I am just lack of experience in mathematic proof. Thanks for your time

Comment: One counter example is enough to break the linear property. So unless $b=c=0$ the linear property doesn't hold in general for a general polynomial $p$. Perhaps it does work for some $p$, although i doubt it, but that is not what is being asked to prove.

Answer (score 1):

A proof is either correct or not.  There's no issue of *danger*.

I dare say mathematics is not dangerous.   Nobody ever cut himself on an integral (though metaphorically, yes, to be sure).

One might come up with a simpler, more elegant proof,  say;   but I don't think it's very likely in this case.

Mathematicians tend to prefer simpler proofs, for fairly obvious reasons.    Btw, the polynomials used are degree zero, that is,constant polynomials.   They are in a sense the simplest types of polynomials.

So, in sum, I think it's clearly inexperience at this point.  But don't worry.  Practice makes perfect.

Comment: Hi, Chris thanks for your answer. I think it addresses my question. But if possible, why do you think "it's very likely in this case"? Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Hi.  I _don't_ think it's likely,  because the task was accomplished in pretty short order.  Using,  as I said,  very simple polynomials.   How much more direct a proof could we ask for?

Comment: Interesting~ It just comes to me that can I demonstrate that a!=0 or b!=0 cannot meet the condition when f(x)=pi/2 and g(x)=pi/2, and prove that the only possibility left is a=0 and b=0? Or Can I use induction on the degree? But it's not easy to deal with the sin(p(0))?

Comment: Frankly I think you're (probably)  complicating things unnecessarily.  But that's just my opinion.   Suit yourself.   Playing around with these things _is_ how you learn mathematics.